# The method 'FocusTrapArea' isn't defined for the class '_PinputState?

Tags: flutter, input

I have tried repairing the cache using flutter pub cache repairand also cleaned the project cache using flutter clean.It still doesn't work.

/C:/Users/Phili/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pinput-2.2.20/lib/src/pinput_state.dart:339:14: Error: The method 'FocusTrapArea' isn't defined for the class '_PinputState'.

- '_PinputState' is from 'package:pinput/src/pinput.dart' ('/C:/Users/Phili/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pinput-2.2.20/lib/src/pinput.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FocusTrapArea'.
  child: FocusTrapArea(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Failed to compile application.

anyone answer please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I cloned a flutter open source project from Github.
I resolved it by upgrading the `pinput` package to its latest version.

At the time of writing this answer, the latest `pinput` version is `2.2.31`.

Follow these steps:

1. In your `pubspec.yaml` file, change the `pinput` to the latest version.
2. In the terminal, run `flutter clean`
3. Then run `flutter run`, it will internally call flutter pub get for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sorry this is coming late! I experienced mine when I updated my Flutter version to 3.7 so what I did was to update the Piput package version to the latest version and that solved mine for me. I hope it helps. I could not fully figure out what happen why it broke my app the first time but it was intuitive for me to upgrade the pinput package.

Answer (score 1):

Have this issue on pinput version 2.2.21
Doing this in my pubspec solve it

```
pinput:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_Pinput
    ref: dev
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is to delete my pubspec.lock then running `flutter clean` command. hope it'll work for you